# Riddle - First and foremost

Tags: riddle

Answer the following riddle:

> First and foremost,
>   but ultimately nothing.
>   Assistance inverted
>   is a thing of beauty.

Who am I?

Hint:

> Assistance (as referenced in this puzzle) would fit the bill, inverted or not.

Hint 2:

> A couple of you are dancing around the first two lines.  For the second two lines, think Bo Derek playing basketball.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I now think you are:

> Ten

First and foremost

> number 1

but ultimately nothing

> number 0

make

> 10

Assistance inverted

> Invert 10 giving a tenth and this gives dime from: 
>  Etymology: French dîme, from Latin decimus ‎(“tenth”) 
>  A dime is a slang term for an assist (basketball)

is a thing of beauty

> In gymnastics a score of 10 has been called perfect

Hint 1: Assistance (as referenced in this puzzle) would fit the bill, inverted or not.

> A dime is slang for a very attractive person

Hint 2:  For the second two lines, think Bo Derek playing basketball.

> 10 -- the unforgettable film starring Bo D and Dudley

Comment: You are so close that I'm tempted to mark yours as correct.

Comment: I tried this answer again :)

Comment: Close enough.  The answer I originally had in mine was what you have minus the adjective.  Your reasoning is only missing the "inverted" part.  Think fractions.

Comment: Thanks for *all the help*. I think I have the answer now.

Answer (score 8):

Can it be

> Zero

First and foremost

> Zero is the first number

But ultimately nothing

> Zero does not have any value

Assistance inverted thing of Beauty

> As per the hint if the bill comes 0 it is kind of assistance as we don't need to pay it

Comment: You're on the right track

Comment: M@Kevin about the explanation or answer?

Comment: the second part of your explanation is correct.

Comment: Check the clues I added

Answer (score 7):

Referring to @Kevin comment about @LearningPhase getting on the right track, my answer could be:

> ∅

Explanation:

> It is nothing. In set theory it stands for {} or "empty set" what is (generally speaking) nothing.
>  
>  
>  
>  "First and foremost" - before *something* (or *everything*) there is *nothing*.
>  
>  "but ultimately nothing." - that is what is it.
>  
>  "Assistance inverted is a thing of beauty" - it you insert *something* into *nothing* is not anymore *nothing* and can become *anything*.

Answer (score 1):

It is a long shot but ...

> I think you are "zerodiva"

Reasoning:

First and foremost,
but ultimately nothing.

> This is number zero it is first but it is nothing

Assistance inverted
is a thing of beauty.

> Assistance = AID and if you invert it div and a thing of beauty diva
>  So result is zerodiva [link](https://zerodiva.bandcamp.com/)

Comment: Where did you get the V from?

Answer (score -1):

Referring to @Kevin's comment about @LearningPhase being on the right track, my answer could be:

Could it be:

> everything

First and foremost

> Everyone wants it

but ultimately nothing.

> But then having everything ends up being boring.

Assistance inverted

> Giving people aid since you have everything

is a thing of beauty.

> Assistance is often respected.